# Is the profinite completion of $SL_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ isomorphic to $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Is the profinite completion of $SL_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ isomorphic to $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$ ?

Does anything change if we replace $SL$ with $GL$?

Comment: You should be more specific because there is confusion on whether you treat groups as abstract group or topological group. Profinite completion as abstract group? isomorphic as abstract or topological groups? Anyway the answer will be "no" because the second group, but not the first, admits, say, $\mathrm{PSL}_3(\mathbf{F}_3)$ as a quotient (probably the right-hand group admits all nonabelian simple groups of order divisible by 3 as quotient, the left-hand one only admits the $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ ones).

Comment: @YCor I'm confused, I've never heard of profinite completions of anything other than abstract groups. The profinite completion is the inverse limit w.r.t. all finite quotients, right?

Comment: If $G$ is a topological group, the profinite completion of the topological group $G$ is the inverse limit of all $G/H$ where $H$ ranges over open finite index subgroups.